# Make list view drop-down sort permanently visible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, css, html

is there a way to make the drop-down arrow permanently visible on a SharePoint list header instead of only having it on mouse hover?

If i remove the "img style="visibility: hidden;" tag in IE debugger it displays, but i cant seem to emulate this through css, As it seems to be called from a mouse over.

```
<a title="Open Menu" class="ms-headerSortArrowLink" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" href="javascript:;"><img style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/ecbarw.png?rev=23" ms-jsgrid-click-passthrough="true" ""="" +="" stshtmlencode(strings.sts.l_openmenu)=""></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use script Web part and insert a tag style

.ms-headerSortArrowLink{visibility:visibility !important; } 
The important should override the in line style